# Why aren't whole program optimizations more prevalent now?

Tags: language-agnostic, optimization

Main question: Why aren't general or even specialized whole program optimizers part of our daily lives?

I started thinking about this after reading SuperCompilers, LLC's [White paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20020814020557/http://www.supercompilers.com/white_paper.shtml), which discusses their method of "supercompiling" or [metacompiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacompilation) a program's source to (generally) achieve a faster version that does the same functionality as the original program.  Essentially they step through a program's execution and recompile to the same target language.  By doing this, natural optimizations occur; for instance, a general binary search function might be specialized to binary search an array of 100 items, if the input program uses arrays of 100 items frequently.

[Partial Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation) is a perhaps a more narrow type of whole program optimization, where the program's source is reduced/evaluated based on some fixed set of input while leaving unknown input open to be evaluated at runtime.  For instance, a general function x ^ y, if given that y = 5, can be reduced to x ^ 5 or perhaps something like (x * x) * (x * x) * x.

(I apologize for my crude descriptions of these two techniques)

Historically whole program optimizations such as the two above would be too memory intensive to perform, but with our machines have gigs of memory (or using something like the cloud), why haven't we seen lots of open source partial evaluators and the like spring up?  I have seen some, but I would have thought this would be a regular part of our tool chain.

- Is it fear (programmer fearing the transformation of their code introducing bugs)?
- Is it just not worth it
  (i.e. for web apps the bottleneck is
  I/O, and this kind of optimization
  seems to be saving CPU time)?
- Is this
  kind of software just that difficult
  to write?
- Or, is my perception of
  this just wrong?

Comment: Powerful optimizer *are* everywhere. Not only do the static optimizer on main line compilers do considerable AST rewriting, but the optimizer on JIT compilers do use case specialization. There hasn't been a revolution because these thing happened incrementally.

Comment: Do the compiler/interpreter optimizations overcome the need for a stand-alone tool?  One example I've seen in the case of interpreted languages is partially evaluating the interpreter source with a program's source to create a compiled version of that program.  That should effectively (theoretically) eliminate all the overhead of interpreting the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's mostly that your perception is wrong. Most compilers support "whole program" (interprocedural) optimizations, and profile-guided optimization to guide the optimizer based on actual use.

The main reason most people haven't noticed is that in the end, these rarely make enough difference to really notice are care much about. General availability of such tools also happened around the time that they just didn't matter a lot for most purposes. CPUs are now so fast that nobody thinks twice about having code running on a java virtual machine, which is itself running inside something like a VMWare virtual machine (and it wouldn't even be *particularly* rare to have a *third* virtual machine layer).

That adds overhead that *dwarfs* the improvement you can typically expect from global optimization. For most people, speed differences have to be *quite* large to matter at all anymore (and improvements from global optimization rarely qualify).

Comment: "it wouldn't even be particularly rare to have a third virtual machine layer" - e.g. if you wrote a TTF renderer in Java running on a virtual OS. Or a very likely example, stretching the definition of "VM" to include any interpreter, a Lua interpreter in a .NET game, running on a virtualized Windows.

Comment: @Steve: Yup -- or, (without stretching the definition of a VM at all), a Java program that requires a JVM old enough that you're running it in Windows 7's "XP mode", with Windows 7 itself running under VMWare...

Comment: i don't buy this explaination, yes our machines are "fast" but sometimes you need every bit of performance (why you should have only 1/2 the speed of say a non-supercompiled version of a c++ program with a java vm. Yes you can develop much faster in java than in C++ _but_ its possible to build transformation programs to compile a subset of java into c++ code or something similar.

Comment: @Quonux: You're stuck with one simple fact: despite producing slower results, Java remains in use (and I'm not convinced it provides real productivity improvements either). For that matter, so do lots of other languages that aren't nearly as competitive in terms of execution speed as Java. Even among C++ compilers, the most popular ones (e.g., gcc, MS VC++) do very relatively little optimization beyond what's outlined in the Dragon book. Intel C++ nearly always beats MS, but has essentially 0 market share.

Comment: @JerryCoffin after thinking about SC I come to another point which should only be possibl with SC. With SC the programmer can write highly abstract "library" code (for example an interpreter), so the usage code can invoke the interpreter, and the SC produces code we would write (unroll) today manualy. This is a increbile huge gain in programmer productivity, even in languages like java.

Comment: @JerryCoffin It boils all down to the classic chicken egg problem. If the compiler don't optimize enought nobody does care to write more abstract, useful code (for productivity), because it would slow down the end product some orders of mangnitude.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is a chicken egg problem, let me explain this.

With Supercompilation (SC) the programmer can write more abstract code without paying the runtime costs (for the release build, it may be impractical to do it for every debug build).

So if there (today) no SC's are around, programmers write "low level" code, so nobody writes better code and needs SC's to do the heavy lifting.

The only thing which may prevent SC in the real world is the need for a (very) high level of intelligence for whole program supercompilation. OpenCog or any other AGI-ish AI may be a great help to solve this last problem. This is not the case if only small parts should be SC'ed (like single methods).

Another reason, that SC isn't today common, is that it is relativly new (compared to much older compilation technology), SC was developed in the 70's and the compilation costs scale nonlinear, so its not a target of the big compiler vendors.

With more abstract code I mean

- ability to write datatype independent code, so it would in the end make templates/generics obsolete (for the most part)
- the programmer can invoke at any point any kind of a interpreter, the SC should be in the most cases be able to optimize it completly away so the end result looks like a handcrafted version of the code the programmer has in mind. Without the need to do the manual "unrolling" and a much higher productivity (because the programmer doesn't need to modify the "low level" code, he can work on a much higher level

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking what I consider a deep question, and
please forgive my flame...

Partial Evaluation is a beautiful concept whose beauty has been totally lost in the seemingly endless desire to build clever but brainless tools to take things out of the hands/minds of programmers.
That's why it hasn't done much.

Whenever you write a program A that writes a program B (which is a basic skill that every programmer (in my opinion) should know how to use, and *when* to use) you are doing partial evaluation.
Since some of the input data is known early and does not change often, there's no need for the program to keep testing what it is all the time.
You can take the information that hardly ever changes and pass it as input to A, and have A print out the program B that simply "knows" the static input, so all it has to do is handle the unpredictable dynamic input.

But as soon as somebody tries to write a *tool* to do partial evaluation, they are taking the programmer's brain out of the loop, and that's what kills it.

The same goes for optimization in general.
When the programmer surrenders his/her judgement to a tool, very little results, because there is no tool (yet, at least) that can comprehend the code the way the programmer does.

It is certainly worthwhile to *try* to make tools that understand the code as well as the programmer does, but it is silly to assume that it *has* been done.